# Internal references in docbook 5

Tags: docbook, docbook-5

I tried to write an internal reference to another section in the same document. But references are not working.
There is a reference, which is located in one section in my docbook-article

`<xref linkend="id1</b>" endterm="Управление Роботом из программы short"/>`

The part of another section in this article:

```
<section id="id1">
        <title>Управление Роботом из программы
        </title>
        <titleabbrev id="id1 short"> Управление Роботом из программы
        </titleabbrev>
        <para>
...
</para>
</section>
```

How to write this reference correctly?

And how can I write a reference form one article to the separate section in another?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the `titleabbrev` content as the cross-reference text, use the following markup:

```
<xref linkend="id1" endterm="short"/>
```

and

```
<section xml:id="id1">
    <title>Управление Роботом из программы
    </title>
    <titleabbrev xml:id="short"> Управление Роботом из программы
    </titleabbrev>
    <para>
...
</para>
</section>
```

The cross-reference points to the section with an ID of `id1`. The [`endterm`](http://www.docbook.org/tdg5/en/html/xref.html) value is the ID (`short`) of the element whose content provides the cross-reference text.

Note that in DocBook 5, `xml:id` is used instead of `id`.

---

Regarding cross references between documents, read about `olink` in "DocBook XSL: The Complete Guide": http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/Olinking.html.