# Referencing the text of an element in docbook

Tags: docbook

I'm trying to reference the text of an element in docbook to use it multiple times in a document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE article PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD Simplified DocBook XML V1.0//EN"
"http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/simple/1.0/sdocbook.dtd">
<article>
  <title>DocBook Tutorial</title>
  <articleinfo>
    <author>
      <firstname>Norbert</firstname>
      <surname>none</surname>
    </author>
    <date>tbd</date>
  </articleinfo>
  <section>
    <title>now it comex</title>
    <para xml:id="my.para">I want to used this para multiple times </para>

<!-- Tried the following but it does not work  -->
   <xref linkend="my.para/> 
  </section>
</article>
```

Does anybody have an idea, how to achieve this?

Comment: Please, refine, do you want just to reuse the text multiple times with NO link to the original snippet, or you just want to put a link to the text snippet and this link should contain linked snippet text?

Comment: The latter one. Or with my words: i want to write the text one time but want it to appear in multiple places of the document.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/32810835/407651